# Obtener texto con re PDF - python

Tags: python, regex

Estoy utilizando el método re para extraer el siguiente valor 262.478.324.706 de un texto obtenido de un PDF:

```
page_content = " PESO COLOMBIANO   12997432512.201.60087335812.201.6002.472.383.106**262.478.324.706**TOTAL EN LETRAS"

valorfinal = re.findall(" PESO COLOMBIANO   [- A-Z0-9_]{.*?}TOTAL EN LETRAS",page_content)

 - "            12997432512.201.60087335812.201.6002.472.383.106262.478.324.706"
```

El valor de 262.478.324.706 puede variar según el PDF, ¿como puede ser más preciso?

Answer (score 2):

Según parece, el valor viene encerrado entre asteriscos. Una expresión regular que reconoce eso es:

```
valorfinal = re.findall("\*([\d+\.?]+)\*",page_content)
```

Que se lee: reconocer una combinación de dígitos `"\d+"` y puntos opcionales `"\.*"` una o más veces `"[\d+\.?]+"` y capturarla `"([\d+\.?]+)"`, siempre que esté rodeada de asteriscos por ambos lados: `"\*([\d+\.?]+)\*"`.

Comment: Hi Candid, disculpame ya que por error puse los asteriscos, la variable contiene la siguiente info:                                                                                                page_content=  "PESO COLOMBIANO   12997432512.201.60087335812.201.6002.472.383.106262.478.324.706TOTAL EN LETRAS"  donde el valor que necesito es "262.478.324.706" que está antes de "TOTAL EN LETRAS" siempre pero el valor a la izquierda del que necesito varía en dígitos o len. Gracias por la colaboración